# Listen for {space} input

Tags: autohotkey

When the user presses the spacebar on their keyboard, "some text" should be send.

What's the correct way to listen for a `{space}` input?

---

This results in an error:

`{space}::Send, some text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the curly braces and you'll need to remove the space in your sending text to prevent a loop.

```
Space::Send, sometext
```

KeyList can be found here https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Comment: FYI, I don't get a loop when including the space, it automatically strips it away and thus prints "sometext"

Comment: Use [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) and the [`$`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) modifier is used to prevent self triggering hotkeys.